# Define globals when bundling to umd or commonjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I have a client-side application which makes use of some browser global properties like `Element` or `document`.

I'd like to run my application in node.js as well and currently I am overriding those globals with the [domino dom implementation](https://github.com/fgnass/domino) in my server like so:

```
const domino = require("domino");

const domimpl = domino.createDOMImplementation();
const document = domimpl.createHTMLDocument();

Object.assign(global, Element: domino.impl.Element, document};

const myApp = require('my-app');
```

I am currently using rollup to bundle different versions of `my-app`, how can I have rollup do this for me automatically for the `_server` version of `my-app` so consumers of `my-app` don't have to do that?

I was thinking of writing my own rollup plugin but I feel like overriding globals seems like a common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR; Use separate entry file instead of a rollup plugin.**

Simply add the following instead of a rollup plugin

```
if (typeof window ==== "undefined") {
  const domino = require("domino");    
  const domimpl = domino.createDOMImplementation();
  const document = domimpl.createHTMLDocument();    
  Object.assign(global, Element: domino.impl.Element, document};
}

// my-app code
```

You might be worried about `domino` entering client side code. To fix this, use separate bundles for server and client, wrap the above mocking code in a separate file and use the following in your `my-app`’s main file meant for the server bundle, an approach similar to how React [ships production and development bundles - conditional imports.](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/npm/index.js#L3)

Server main file

```
require(‘./globals-mocking’);
// my-app client code
```

Client main file

```
// my-app client code only
```

package’s main file

```
if (SERVER_ONLY) {
  module.exports = require('./my-app-server.js'); 
} else { 
  module.exports = require('./my-app-client.js'); 
}
```

Use rollup's [replace plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace) and define `SERVER_ONLY` (https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace#usage) for server entry only. If you use UglifyJS or simlilar tool that eliminates dead code, you wont have `domino` and duplicated server code.

EDIT: Noticed a minor issue. Condition should be  `if (SERVER_ONLY) {`. Use the following definition along with it for the server entry file.

```
  plugins: [
    replace({
      SERVER_ONLY: JSON.stringify(true)
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for -- but when I do that my main file bundled ends up looking like this:

`(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory() :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
 (factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

module.exports = require('./server');

})));`

Comment: that's a UMD module... notice the single "require('./server')" and that's it, it didn't resolve the require.